Ubuntu SSH Server Not respecting the Network Proxy
I've a ubuntu with a SSH server configured, my ubuntu has a vpn and Network Proxy settings set to manual, but when I connect with SSH this settings seem to not apply to it.
For example if I do "curl ifconfig.me" the ip from the ubuntu terminal is different from the ip from the ssh terminal, the ssh its my ip from outside of the proxy.
How can I enforce my open shh server to respect my ubuntu proxy?
Thanks in advance!
